# Versioning, Calculate date since last update

Tags: versioning

SharePoint 3.0, I'm currently creating a new file repository for Reports. Those reports will be updated every week / months, since I need to keep the old file, I will use the built in Versioning. This part is fairly simple.

What I'm looking to do and that I need help with is the following. I will have something close to 50 different reports, so they will be placed inside a grid. In the grid I would like to see the information when is the last time this file was updated here is what it would look like

__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*___|

|....Report 1....|....Report 2....|....Report 3....|

|.......7 Days......|.....28 Days.....|......8 Days......|

__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*___|

I would like to know How I could be able to extract the "modified" date of the current version of a certain report uploaded. I know it's the "Modified Date" field but since I'm new to that I don't know how to go get it and do the maths to give the number of days that the file has been updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the calculated column formatting to display the number of days between now and the modification date using:

```
DATEDIF([Last Modified], [Today], "d")
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb862071(v=office.12).aspx

You could use a content query web part to display your report name and the calculated column, and style it how you like using CSS.